# I am running myapp\urls.py and getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

an  error is returned the traceback is

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I was expecting myapp\urls.py to run successfully

Comment: What means running `myapp\urls.py`? You normally run django locally with `runserver`. And have you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as mentioned in the error messge?

Comment: I have no idea on how to do so...... it is my first django project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Maxwell Oduor, do you still have the problem, or solved it?

Comment: not yet....so i added "myapp" to the list of installed apps and I try running the "myapp\urls.py" script the traceback is :::     ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package   ::: but i have made some progress

Answer (score 0):

Inside your settings.py, you gonna find a list of django apps, add your created app in the list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '<your app name>'
]
```

Comment: made the changes but still getting the same error message

Comment: your question is not clear. Could you share more details like screenshots of the code? You might not have included the app in the installed app in settings.py or have not properly connected urls.py to views.py.

Comment: how do i share images

Comment: edit your question and put some more informations